# ORDER BY SUM in MySQL based table1_id?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sum, sql-order-by

i have some table that is Table_A, Table_B, Table_C, and Table_D.

```
TABLE_A
id_a | Name
A1   | ASD
A2   | ZXC

TABLE_B
id_b | id_a
B1   | A1
B2   | A2

TABLE_C
id_c | id_b | Value
C1   | B1   | 1
C2   | B1   | 1
C3   | B2   | 1
C4   | B2   | 1
C5   | B2   | 1

TABLE_D
id_d | id_a | Bill
D1   | A1   | 5
D2   | A2   | 10
```

I want get " SUM(table_c.value) as tot1 AND SUM(table_d.bill) as tot2 " for each table_a.id_a, like below:

```
id_a  | SUM_VALUE of table_c | SUM_BILL of table_d
A1    | 2                    | 5
A2    | 3                    | 10
```

I used script, like below:

```
$sql=" SELECT *, SUM(table_c.value) as tot1, SUM(table_d.bill) as tot2
FROM table_a
LEFT JOIN table_b ON table_b.id_a=table_a.id_a
LEFT JOIN table_c ON table_c.id_b=table_b.id_b
GROUP BY id_a ";
```

But, I get a wrong result, like below:

```
id_a  | SUM_VALUE of table_c | SUM_BILL of table_d
A1    | 2                    | 10
A2    | 3                    | 30
```

Anyone help me?
Thanks

Comment: Add sample data and expected result please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*I didn't test it, but **it should works**:*

```
$sqlQuery = "
SELECT *, SUM(`bill`) AS `total_bill` 
FROM `table1` 
LEFT JOIN `table2` 
ON table1.table1_id = table2.table2_id
GROUP BY `table1_id` 
ORDER BY `total_bill` DESC
";

$result = mysql_query($sqlQuery);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    echo "{$row['table1_id']} - {$row['total_bill']}<br>";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SUM(bill) AS total_bill 
from table1, table2 
WHERE table1.table1_id=table2.table2_id 
AND table2_id=$table1_id
Group by table1_id
order by total_bill
```

this should do the trick, you need the group by to get more than 1 result.

Answer (score 0):

Try as below. It should work. If you are using aggregate function on a particular column that column should be add in group by clause.

```
SELECT SUM(bill) AS total_bill 
from table1, table2 
WHERE table1.table1_id=table2.table2_id 
AND table2_id= yourId
Group by table1_id
order by bill;
```